# FileNotFoundException while running code within WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first foray into C# and I've run into an issue I just can't find a resolution to.  I'm developing an app in Visual Studio 2022 where one part of it needs access rights to a remote computer, (to query it for running services).  Since I'm new to C# I'm building isolated tests of each aspect of what I need.  I have code that can get services on my local machine, and I have code that can impersonate a different user, (both copied from Microsoft examples - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-7.0)).  I can also run the code in the same class by calling the impersonation and then stopping impersonation before calling the ServiceController.  But when I try to combine the code to get the services from the remote machine using impersonation the ServiceController dll can't be found when run as a regular user.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController, Version=7.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Identity
  StackTrace:
   at ImpersonationDemo.<>c.<Main>b__1_0() in C:\Users\me\source\repos\TestProjects\Identity\Program.cs:line 75
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal(SafeAccessTokenHandle token, Action action)
   at ImpersonationDemo.Main() in C:\Users\me\source\repos\TestProjects\Identity\Program.cs:line 54
```

I don't want to run Visual Studio as an administrator just to get around this problem, but I did test it by creating two identical projects/solutions, one with my regular account and one with my admin account.  Both required the NuGet System.ServiceProcessServiceController package to be installed.  When deployed the application will run under a service account with appropriate privileges.  I'm just in the early stages of mocking up test code, so production code won't have this kind of thing in it.

Here's my complete combined code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceProcess;

public class Test2
{
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
                    int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeAccessTokenHandle phToken);

public static void Main()
{
    // Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the   
    // unmanaged LogonUser method.   
    // The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.  
    Console.Write("Enter the name of the domain on which to log on: ");
    string domainName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the login of a user on {0} that you wish to impersonate: ", domainName);
    string userName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the password for {0}: ", userName);

    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.   
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

    // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.   
    SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle;
    bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, Console.ReadLine(),
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
        out safeAccessTokenHandle);

    if (false == returnValue)
    {
        int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret);
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Did LogonUser Succeed? " + (returnValue ? "Yes" : "No"));
    // Check the identity.  
    Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

    WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(
        safeAccessTokenHandle,
        // User action  
        () =>
        {
            // Check the identity.  
            Console.WriteLine("During impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            // **** Combined the following into RunImpersonated: ****
            string computerName = "db-test-2022";

            ServiceController[] scServices;
            scServices = ServiceController.GetServices(computerName);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Services running on [{0}]:", computerName));
            foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
            {
                if (scTemp.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service name: {0}\tDisplay name: {1}", scTemp.ServiceName, scTemp.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        });

    // Check the identity again.  
    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
}
}
```

As a recap:

1. Developing under my regular user account I can run both Microsoft code examples without issue.
2. Using my regular user account I can run both parts in the same class code, i.e. do the impersonation successfully, stop impersonation and then get the services.
3. When I combine the code by putting the ServiceController code inside the RunImpersonated scope is when I can no longer find the ServiceController dll.

So my question is what am I doing wrong?  Or alternatively how can I test code that requires elevated privileges without running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: Whose identity is your program impersonating? Can that identity run the service controller code?

Comment: @JohnWu - I have two accounts, a regular user account and an admin account.  Both can run the service controller code, but the regular account can only run it for my local machine of course.  I'm trying to impersonate my admin account while running the code as my regular account to get the services on a remote server.  And that's when I get the error.  I should add that this is running it from Visual Studio, not fully compiled and deployed.  My admin account has full rights on the server.

Comment: Is it possible that `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll` is deployed into a folder that is a subfolder of one of your regular user account's folders (e.g. `My Documents`). If so, the administrator version of you wouldn't be able to see it, since a different folder would be mapped to `My Documents` in that context. Perhaps try deploying your program to a non-user-specific folder.